# Single Scanner statment askes for repeated user input for sorting collections using comparator interface

Tags: java, collections, java.util.scanner, comparator

In the below code the scanner statement request user input multiple times before it can sort.

if there are are n elements to sort it asks the user to input n-1 times and i have tried to debug and couldn't fins the proper reason.

```
package com.sort.ComparableAndComparator;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    private int id,score;
    private String firstname,lastname;
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);

    public Student(int id,int score,String firstname ,String lastname){
        this.id=id;
        this.score=score;
        this.firstname=firstname;
        this.lastname=lastname;
    }
    //getters and setters
    public int getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

    public int getScore() {return score;}

    public void setScore(int score) {this.score = score;}

    public String getFirstname() {return firstname;}

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {this.firstname = firstname;}

    public String getLastname() {return lastname;}

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {this.lastname = lastname;}


    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student studentObj) {
        //user input
        System.out.println("1:sortby ID 2:sortby SCORE 3:sortby FIRSTNAME 4:sortby LASTNAME");
        int input=scan.nextInt();
        //switch statement
        switch(input){
        case 1:System.out.println("comapring ids");
        if(this.getId()<studentObj.getId()){
            System.out.println("comparing "+this.getId()+" "+studentObj.getId());
            return -1;
        }else if(this.getId()>studentObj.getId()){
            System.out.println("comparing "+this.getId()+" "+studentObj.getId());
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;

        case 2:System.out.println("comapring scores");
        if(this.getScore()<studentObj.getScore()){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.getScore()>studentObj.getScore()){
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;

        case 3:System.out.println("comapring firstname");
        if(this.getFirstname().compareTo(studentObj.getFirstname())<0){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.getFirstname().compareTo(studentObj.getFirstname())>0){
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;

        case 4:System.out.println("comapring lastname");
        if(this.getLastname().compareTo(studentObj.getLastname())<0){
            return -1;
        }else if(this.getLastname().compareTo(studentObj.getLastname())>0){
            return 1;
        }else
            return 0;

        default:System.out.println("no correct input selected!!!");
        return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student [id=" + id + ", score=" + score + ", firstname="
                + firstname + ", lastname=" + lastname +"]"+"---";
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> studentList=new ArrayList<Student>();
        studentList.add(new Student(1,42,"john","b"));
        studentList.add(new Student(2,52,"bob","e"));
        studentList.add(new Student(5,44,"christian","g"));
        studentList.add(new Student(7,44,"jerry","j"));
        System.out.println("Sortinng!!!");
        Collections.sort(studentList);
        System.out.println("sorting completed!!");
        System.out.println(studentList+"\n");
    }

}
```

Comment: Expected behavior is missing in your problem statement.

Comment: @mattias,could you give a hint where am going wrong?

Comment: Rather than looking through the code and trying to understand what it _should_ do, rather than what it _is doing_ when you have no exceptions, null pointers etc, it is kind of nice to get a clear problem statement like the following: "Hello, I have code <my code>. I expect that output should be 5 when I input 2, but output is 4. Why?"